# When to pull out a negative sign from a variable

Tags: coordinate-systems, conventions

I get confused about when there should be a negative sign in certain equations or not. I will give three short examples (that I will make long with explanation) that show my confusion.

Example 1: Rockets.
Consider a rocket of mass $m$ traveling in the positive x direction with velocity $v$. The ejected fuel has a velocity relative to the rocket $v_{ex}$. At time $t$, the rocket's momentum is $P(t) = mv$. In a short time later, $t + dt$, the rocket's mass is $m + dm$ (where $dm$) is negative and momentum $P(t + dt) = (m + dm)(v + dv)$. The fuel ejected in a time $dt$ has mass (-$dm$) and velocity $v - v_{ex}$ relative to ground. The total momentum at time $t + dt$ is

$$P(t+dt) = (m+dm)(v+dv) - dm(v-v_{ex})$$
$$ = mv + mdv + dmv_{ex}$$

1a) Why is the negative contained in the $dm$ of the rocket mass while the negative is pulled out of the $dm$ for the fuel? To reconcile this, I thought of something like, if ejecting mass is a positive, then use positive $dm$ as they did in the text from which I'm reading out of. So ejecting means positive, while the fuel gains mass in a way. So I can define gaining mass with a $-dm$ as they did. However, if I was doing this problem, I would have made ejecting mass negative and gaining mass positive. But if I change the sign on all of the $dm$'s I don't get the same result in the text.

Example 2: I'm not reading this one out of a text but I can explain the question. Often times you'll see something like

$$\frac{d(Q)}{dx} = ax$$

where $Q$ is some function. The book or whatever will then say, but as $x$ increases $Q$ decreases so the expression should really be

$$\frac{d(Q)}{dx} = - ax$$

2a) Why can't the negative sign be contained in the constant of proportionality? Does it change the result? All it does by putting a minus sign there is force $a$ to be positive.

Example 3: Projectile motion with quadratic drag. The equation of motion for this is given by

$$m\ddot{\vec{r}} = m\vec{g} - cv^2\hat{v} = m\vec{g} - cv\vec{v}$$
where $v$ is the magnitude of the velocity of the projectile. If we only look in the vertical direction, with y measured vertically upwards, my text gives

$$m\ddot{v_y} = -mg - c\sqrt{v^2_x + v^2_y}v_y$$

3a) So $\vec{g} = -g\hat y$ and they pulled negative out of the $g$. So it makes sense that its $-mg$ since y is pointed upwards. Why isn't it $+ c\sqrt{...}$? Is the reason because $v_y$ is negative, so a negative times a negative is a positive? If so, why did the negative come out of the $g$ while the negative was kept inside the $v_y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example #1, you need to remember that mass is conserved. The stream of exhaust left behind by the rocket grows in mass by exactly the rate the rocket consumes fuel.

In your example #2, there's often a desire to make constants positive. If that constant is actually negative in your interpretation of the problem, you need to add a minus sign.

In your example #3, the above is exactly what is happening. Gravitational acceleration is 9.80665 m/s<sup>2</sup>. You've adopted a sign convention that denotes up is positive *y*. Gravitational acceleration is down, so you need to add that minus sign in front of the positive value of *g* to match your sign convention. This problem would vanish had you instead adopted the convention that down is positive *y* (but now other problems would arise).

Bottom line: You need to be very careful of sign conventions.